# How to inject Array with an object only if the object is not exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my empty Array

```
locations = []
```

and I have another Array with locations and city's

```
Data = [
    { location: "01" , city: "01"},
    { location: "01" , city: "02"},
    { location: "03" , city: "03"},
    { location: "04" , city: "04"},
    { location: "01" , city: "01"},
    { location: "01" , city: "01"}
]
```

how can I loop through array `Data[]` and add the objects in `locations[]` without repeating it like first objects and last two objects

```
locations = [
    { location: "01" , city: "01"},
    { location: "01" , city: "02"},
    { location: "02" , city: "02"},
    { location: "03" , city: "03"},
    { location: "04" , city: "04"}
]
```

Comment: You're looking for distinct locations from `data` array yes ?

Comment: Keep a side array with your object hash or id and do a linear lookup in this array to determine if you insert or not into locations.

Comment: take a look https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqBy

Comment: Thanks guys for your help <3 Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do the job

```
Data = [
  { location: "01", city: "01" },
  { location: "01", city: "02" },
  { location: "03", city: "03" },
  { location: "04", city: "04" },
  { location: "01", city: "01" },
  { location: "01", city: "01" }
]

const locations = Data.reduce( ( acc, d ) => {
  if ( !acc.some( ( a ) => a.city == d.city && a.location == d.location ) ) {
    acc.push( d )
  }
  return acc
}, [] )

console.log( locations )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to filter out the duplicates and get a unique array of objects, `locations`:

```js
var Data = [
{ location: "01" , city: "01"},
{ location: "01" , city: "02"},
{ location: "03" , city: "03"},
{ location: "04" , city: "04"},
{ location: "01" , city: "01"},
{ location: "01" , city: "01"}
];
var locations = Data.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  var exist = acc.find(({location, city}) => obj.location === location && obj.city === city);
  if(!exist){
    acc.push(obj);
  }
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: is this O(N^2) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply `forEach` and push value with combination of `location` and `city` separated by `"_"`

```js
var locations = {}

var Data = [
{ location: "01" , city: "01"},
{ location: "01" , city: "02"},
{ location: "03" , city: "03"},
{ location: "04" , city: "04"},
{ location: "01" , city: "01"},
{ location: "01" , city: "01"}
]

Data.forEach(val=>{ 
 var key = val.location+"_"+val.city;
 locations[key] = val;
 });
 
 locations = Object.values(locations);
 
 console.log(locations);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `.filter()` and `.map()` methods, like this:

```
var locations = Data.filter((d,i) => Data.map(dt => dt.location).indexOf(d.location) == i);
```

**Demo:**

```js
Data = [
{ location: "01" , city: "01"},
{ location: "01" , city: "02"},
{ location: "03" , city: "03"},
{ location: "04" , city: "04"},
{ location: "01" , city: "01"},
{ location: "01" , city: "01"}
];

var locations = Data.filter((d,i) => Data.map(dt => dt.location).indexOf(d.location) == i);
console.log(locations);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function unique(a, key) {
            var seen = {};
            return a.filter(function (item) {
                item = key ? item[key] : item;
                return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
            });
        }
//var locations= unique(Data , "city");
var locations= unique(unique(Data , "city") , "location");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `Array.filter()` and `Set()`(each entry of set a combination of city and location). If an element is not present in set than add it and add that element to set also. Try the following:

```js
let Data = [ { location: "01" , city: "01"}, { location: "01" , city: "02"}, { location: "03" , city: "03"}, { location: "04" , city: "04"}, { location: "01" , city: "01"}, { location: "01" , city: "01"} ];
let set = new Set();

let result = Data.filter((e)=>{
   var key = e.location + "_" + e.city;
  if(!set.has(key)){
    set.add(key);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the location name as key to to an object for uniqness check, and then return the object values once you completed the array iteration using `Array.reduce`.

```js
var data = [{
    location: "01",
    city: "01"
  },
  {
    location: "01",
    city: "02"
  },
  {
    location: "03",
    city: "03"
  },
  {
    location: "04",
    city: "04"
  },
  {
    location: "01",
    city: "01"
  },
  {
    location: "01",
    city: "01"
  }
]

var result = data.reduce((mem, cur) => {
  var key = `{cur.location}--${cur.city}`
  if (!mem[key]) {
    mem[key] = cur;
  }
  return mem
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Yes I saw that. The OP wanted I think only by location name uniq. as per the output mentioned in the question. The OP has just `{ location: "01" , city: "01"},` .. in the expected output.

Comment: The output seem to have typo in second object `location: "02" , city: "02"` because the `city:02` is only there for `location :01`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Oh I see. I fixed it.